# What is a source of model distortion of this kind

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

i'm proting the code from old project to the new one. The old was based on GLFW, new is based on the GLFW3. There were some modification to objects used to store the data, and on a first glance the end result shouldn't be changed but in reality it produces a distorted image. I assume it's something to do with MVP matrices.

The screenshot of [the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMKYP.jpg). It supposed to be two boxes ^_^

The draw method draws object with specified base color and a light source (hard-coded for the moment):

```
glm::mat4 view, model, mvp, projection;

Mesh* mesh = (Mesh*)rm.Get(renderable->model);
Position* frame = (Position*)positions->Get( renderable->owner );
int program_id = ((Shader*)rm.Get(renderable->program))->program_id;

//vertex buffer
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->vertex.buffer_id );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

//normal buffer
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->normal.buffer_id );
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (void*)0 );

//texture uv buffer
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->uv.buffer_id );
glVertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

glUseProgram( program_id );

view = camera->view;
projection = camera->projection;
mvp = projection * view * frame->mat4;

//set color
GLint base_color = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "base_color" );
if( base_color != -1 )
    glUniform3f( base_color, renderable->diffuse_color.r, 
                             renderable->diffuse_color.g, 
                             renderable->diffuse_color.b );

glm::vec4 light_pos = glm::vec4( 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glm::vec4 light = glm::normalize( glm::inverse( frame->mat4 ) * light_pos );

GLint light_position = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "light_position" );
if( light_position != -1 )  glUniform3f( light_position, light.x, light.y, light.z );

GLint light_ambient = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "light_ambient" );
if( light_ambient != -1 )   glUniform3f( light_ambient, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f );

GLint light_diffuse = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "light_diffuse" );
if( light_diffuse != -1 )   glUniform3f( light_diffuse, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f );

GLint mvp44 = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "MVP" );
glUniformMatrix4fv( mvp44, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0] );

// Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh->vertex.size / 3 );

glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
```

The view and projection matrix calculation method:

```
camera->target = glm::vec3(position->x_axis) - glm::vec3{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
camera->view = glm::lookAt( glm::vec3( position->position ), camera->target, glm::vec3( position->y_axis ) );
camera->projection = glm::perspective( camera->fovy, camera->aspect, camera->near_r, camera->far_r );
```

The camera struct:

```
struct Camera: public Component {
    glm::mat4       projection;
    glm::mat4       view;
    glm::vec3       target;
    glm::vec3       up;

    float       fovy;
    float       aspect;
    float       near_r;
    float       far_r;

    bool        directed;
```

};

The position struct:

```
struct Position: public Component {
    union {
        struct {
            glm::mat4 mat4;
        };

        struct {
            glm::vec4 x_axis;
            glm::vec4 y_axis;
            glm::vec4 z_axis;
            glm::vec4 position;
        };

        struct {
            glm::vec4 fwd;
            glm::vec4 up;
            glm::vec4 right;
            glm::vec4 position;
        };
    };
};
```

The mesh struct contains only corresponding buffer id's and their size.

The camera initialization data:

```
camera->up = glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

camera->fovy = 65.0f;
camera->aspect = 4.0f / 3.0f;
camera->near_r = 0.1f;
camera->far_r = 100.0f;
camera->directed = true;
```

The position initilization data:

```
position->position = glm::vec4{ 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
position->fwd = glm::vec4{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
position->up = glm::vec4{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
position->right = glm::vec4{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
```

Shader and model data and their loading/binding functions are unchanged from the previous project and shouldn't cause trouble.

The content of the MVP matrix:

```
r=0.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=7.81581593 a=8.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=1.56968546  b=6.81381416 a=7.00000000
r=1.17726409  g=0.000000000 b=6.81381416 a=7.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=5.01000977 a=5.00000000
```

For the position:

```
r=1.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=0.000000000 a=1.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=1.000000000 b=0.000000000 a=1.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=1.000000000 a=1.00000000
r=5.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=0.000000000 a=1.00000000
```

Comment: (Probably) unrelated, but why the cast fest in the first lines ?

Comment: Partially because of how i store data and partially because of stuff being hard coded into function for debugging purposes. I dropped using templates since they were turning code into mess in the previous iteration of the program in favor of interfaces. But the outcome is that every storage returns abstract Component type which needs to be casted into required type. The same goes for Resource storage.

Comment: Ouch. You may want to, at least, use `static_cast`s instead of C-style casts, and `dynamic_cast` when you want a checked downcast in exchange for a few CPU cycles. That will probably save you a few hours of pulling your hair out when you accidentally cast to the wrong type :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture in the question is a result of two problems. First was in the model matrix for which i used position. For my case it should have being:

```
r=1.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=0.000000000 a=0.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=1.000000000 b=0.000000000 a=0.00000000
r=0.000000000 g=0.000000000 b=1.000000000 a=0.00000000
r=1.000000000 g=1.000000000 b=1.000000000 a=1.00000000
```

It describe position of an object located at the 1.1.1 coordinates. Normaly, the last column is used to store position, but when i wrote the code around two years ago i used transposed matrix and happily forgot about it. So, the initial matrix was correct for normal model matrix, but not for transposed.

After fixing it it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGTmr.jpg). Those artifacts are responsible for appearance of the weird shape. Which are [fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Akw4.jpg) by enabling GL_DEPTH_TEST.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you a re rewriting the Vertex attribute with your matrix

`GLint mvp44 = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "MVP" );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( 0, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0] );`

Try using the uniform location you have queried :

     `GLint mvp44 = glGetUniformLocation( program_id, "MVP" );
     glUniformMatrix4fv( mvp44, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0] );`

Comment: Sorry, i was probing code by randomly hard coding stuff to see what could break and didn't edit it back. The result is the same.

Comment: Okay then, that was odd.
Your position[3][3] value is 0.0, which is also odd

Comment: I fixed it, [the result](http://imgur.com/g3pk6lK) is a little different, but still wrong.

Comment: I have no much more clues for you exept this one : Be carefull with the ordering of your matrices. GLM uses column major (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)

Try this init : 

position->position = glm::vec4{ 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
position->fwd = glm::vec4{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0f };
position->up = glm::vec4{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
position->right = glm::vec4{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };